# git-tag list only those tags that are at or below current HEAD

Tags: git

In my project, I use special tags (`release-tags`) to mark releases. There are some scripts that rely on successive `release-tags` to get change logs and other build specific information.

When I'm releasing from tip of a branch, my scripts extracts tags `N` and `N-1` as below and uses it for processing.

```
git tag --merged master --sort=-creatordate | head -2
```

Sometimes, I have to checkout a specific `release-tag` and rebuild from that point. In this case I intend to extract tags `N-7` (where `HEAD` is pointing to) and `N-8` but end up with the same `N` and `N-1` tags.

So, is there a way I can get (most recent two) tags that are at or below HEAD instead of all the tags in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the tag name instead of branch name (`--merged tag_name`) lists only tags that are below it.

```
git tag --merged tag_name --sort=-creatordate | head -2
```